# Проблемы с написанием флеш-приложения.

Tags: actionscript

Добрый вечер, уважаемые веб-разработчики и программисты. Надеюсь , что Вы потратите минутку времени и поможете мне написать код, выбирающий игрока в flash-приложении случайным образом. Дело в том, что я пишу приложение для соц.сети "ВКонтакте". Это типичный "аукцион" "ВКонтакте", которых очень много в этой соц.сети. Понимаю, что это уже давно не креативный замысел, но попробовать все-таки стоит! В общем, хотелось бы, чтобы моё приложение случайный образом выбирало участника и ему перечислялась определённая сумма "голосов". Как мне быть?

Comment: Перевод голосов пользователям прямо запрещен администрацией в правилах к приложениям ВК.

    Переводить голоса ВКонтакте пользователям любыми способами, за    исключением случаев возврата ранее внесенных голосов и случаев, согласованных с администрацией.

http://vk.com/page-1_3552041

Comment: Тогда, как сделать возможным перевод "голосов" в приложение?

Comment: Например вызвать вконтактовский метод API "showOrderBox" 

    Интеграция этого окна в приложение позволяет его пользователям оплачивать голосами виртуальные товары и переводить голоса на счёт приложения. 
Для начала работы с платежами необходимо реализовать обработку уведомлений на серверной стороне приложения.

http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B9